# Calculate numerically an integral in R

Tags: r, mean, sample, integral

I am trying to learn R and I am using the book "Discovering statistics using R".
I am stuck on this question:

[image]

I am not sure what I have to do, I don't understand what `h(x)` is. All I have done was calculate this:

```
f <- function(x) x*(x^5-1)
integrate(f,0,1)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: In R, `runif(1000)` will give you 1000 elements from the uniform in the unit interval (which means the uniform distribution from 0 to 1). So the first step is: `x <- runif(1000)`.

Comment: It's important to note that for intervals other than [0, 1] (such as, [a, b] = [-1, 1] or [0.5, 1]), you must explicitly multiply the result by the difference—(b-a).

Comment: Look at section 6 of the document at this location—https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-086-numerical-computation-for-mechanical-engineers-fall-2014/nutshells-guis/MIT2_086F14_Monte_Carlo.pdf It's more explicit w.r.t. the derivation.

Answer (score 1):

Doing by the indicated method:

```
f=function(x)x*(x^5-1)
> x=runif(10000)
> mean(f(x))
[1] -0.3571168
```

compare:

```
> integrate(f,0,1)
-0.3571429 with absolute error < 4e-15
```